# Simple injector - can I intercept object creation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I know I can use `container.Options.RegisterResolveInterceptor` to get notified each time an object is resolved, but for my scenario, I'd like to get notified only when the object was created.

For instance, if the type was registered as `Lifestyle.Singleton`, I'd want my delegate to run the first time the type is resolved (when the singleton instance gets created) but not on subsequent calls to resolve.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found, the `RegisterResolveInterceptor` allows intercepting a type that gets resolved directly from the container. This means if you call `GetInstance<ILogger>()`, the `RegisterResolveInterceptor` allows to be wrapped around the `ILogger`, but it won't go off do any of its dependencies.

To hook onto the creation of a type, you can use one of the `RegisterInitializer` overloads. `RegisterInitializer` is primarily means to add some additional initialization to a type that is created by Simple Injector, but there are other interesting use cases for it.

In case you have a specific type you want to get notified about, you can use the `RegisterInitializer<T>(Action<T>)` overload, where you specify the type or abstraction you are interested in. For instance:

```
container.RegisterInitializer<ILogger>(logger =>
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(logger.ToString());
});
```

In this case, the initializer will get hooked to any registration that is assignable from `ILogger`, for instance:

```
container.Register<ILogger>(() => new DbLogger());
container.Register<ILogger, FileLogger>();
container.Register<EventLogLogger>();
```

All three registrations (assuming `EventLogLogger` implements `ILogger`) will get enriched with the initializer.

If however there isn't a particular type or abstraction you want to hook onto, but rather a wide range of types, or you need to have more information about the type (such as its lifestyle), you can use the second `RegisterInitializer` overload. This overload takes in an action that will be executed and a predicate that allows you to specify to which registrations the action will be supplied to. For instance:

```
container.RegisterInitializer(
    data => System.Console.WriteLine(data.Registration.ImplementationType.Name),
    context => context.Registration.Lifestyle == Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

The previous code snippet registers an initializer that will writes the name of the type created to the console, in case that registration is a `Singleton`. An example what you can do with this can be found in the [Glimpse plugin for Simple Injector](https://github.com/simpleinjector/glimpse). The Glimpse plugin [uses](https://github.com/simpleinjector/glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.SimpleInjector/SimpleInjectorTab.cs#L62) this `RegisterInitializer` overload so it can inform the user which types are created during a particular request.

Comment: Thanks Steven! The second overload of RegisterInitializer is exactly what I was looking for, since I need to handle any type. It's for a library of mine that tracks objects (persists and applies their properties). E.g. window locations, and sizes, config settings, last entered data etc... By integrating with IOC, with one line of code I can hook up tracking for all objects that get created by the container, which is seriously neat!

Comment: I'll just put this here (https://github.com/anakic/Jot) in case you're curious enough to take a peek:)